# Is there a way to cache only images only on one webpage?

Tags: caching, meta-tags

I want to cache images only on specific pages on my website.

It is very important that the all images are not cached, so I want to do 1 page at a time.

Can I do this using META TAGS or PHP or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work.

```
<?php
//Caching

//get the last-modified-date of this very file
$lastModified=filemtime(__FILE__);
//get a unique hash of this file (etag)
$etagFile = md5_file(__FILE__);
//get the HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE header if set
$ifModifiedSince=(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] : false);
//get the HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH header if set (etag: unique file hash)
$etagHeader=(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) ? trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) : false);

//set last-modified header
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $lastModified)." GMT");
//set etag-header
header("Etag: $etagFile");
//make sure caching is turned on
header('Cache-Control: public');

//check if page has changed. If not, send 304 and exit
if (@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])==$lastModified || $etagHeader == $etagFile)
{
       header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
       exit;
}

//your normal code
//echo "This page was last modified: ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s",time());

//END OF Caching
?>
```